# How to remove ROOT folder from a Docker Container running Tomcat base image

Tags: apache, tomcat, docker

I want to know whether if there is any method to remove the ROOT folder within the tomcat /webapps folder after its being deployed by a Docker image.

The reason that I want to achieve this is  that I want to run my .war file as the root. I have already renamed my war file as ROOT.war. But when I run my Docker image with the tomcat base image, a ROOT folder is also created by default within the container's tomcat/webapps folder which doesn't allow me to access my ROOT.war file as the root.

**My Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM tomcat:8.0.30-jre7

# Copy to images tomcat path
COPY /ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Answer (score 13):

Sure. You can just delete the already existing ROOT folder as part of your Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image
FROM tomcat:8.0.30-jre7

# Delete existing ROOT folder
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

# Copy to images tomcat path
COPY ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Comment: I added it, but when I go in to the container after running the docker image with the above configs the ROOT folder still exists within the webapps folder. Any thoughts on why this is happening?